Display or hide a div based on a clicked tabs' class
I have tabs setup correctly i.e tab headings and the content is displaying correctly. However I want to also display a separate  DIV just beneath the tabs based on which tabs is active.
So far I have gotten the correct extra div to display on initial page load but clicking on the other tab headings is not changing the displayed div.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".accomodation-tabs .sppb-tab-content .sppb-tab-pane");
  const galleryModules = {
    "standard-twin": ".twin-room-gallery",
    "standard-double": ".standard-double-gallery",
    "luxury-suites": ".luxury-suites-gallery"
  };

  // Hide all modules within the common container
  const allModules = document.querySelectorAll(".accomodation-gallery .sppb-addon");
  allModules.forEach((module) => {
    module.style.display = "none";
  });

  // Show the first gallery module (Twin Room Gallery) on page load
  const twinRoomModule = document.querySelector(".twin-room-gallery");
  twinRoomModule.style.display = "block";

  // Add event listener to tab container
  const tabContainer = document.querySelector(".accomodation-tabs .sppb-tab-content");
  tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const clickedTab = event.target.closest(".sppb-tab-pane");
    if (!clickedTab) return; // Ignore clicks outside tabs

    // Hide all gallery modules
    Object.values(galleryModules).forEach((moduleClass) => {
      document.querySelector(moduleClass).style.display = "none";
    });

    // Show the corresponding gallery module based on the clicked tab
    const tabClass = clickedTab.classList[1];
    const moduleToShow = galleryModules[tabClass];
    document.querySelector(moduleToShow).style.display = "block";
  });
});


Can you also please post html and css code?

With a little CSS; flex box layout, next-sibling combinator, and :has(), you can show and hide elements using radio buttons.
Update
I didn't notice the "However I want to also display a separate DIV just beneath the tabs" in the first place. So, I updated the example with specific CSS selectors in the case that an extra <div class="add"> is present, it should show.


section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section label {
  order: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: start;
  padding: .2em;
  border: solid thin transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}

section label:has(input:checked) {
  background: white;
  border: solid thin;
  border-color: black black transparent;
  border-radius: .3em .3em 0 0;
}

section label:has(input:checked)+div.content {
  display: block;
}

section label.one:has(input:checked)~div.add.one {
  display: block;
}

section label.two:has(input:checked)~div.add.two {
  display: block;
}

section label.three:has(input:checked)~div.add.three {
  display: block;
}

section input {
  display: none;
}

section div.content {
  order: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid black thin;
  min-height: 5em;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

section div.add {
  order: 3;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
<section>
  <label class="one"><input type="radio" name="tab" checked>Tab one</label>
  <div class="content">Content one</div>
  <label class="two"><input type="radio" name="tab">Tab two</label>
  <div class="content">Content two</div>
  
  <label class="three"><input type="radio" name="tab">Tab three</label>
  <div class="content">Content three</div>
  <div class="add two">Add 2</div>
  <div class="add three">Add 3</div>
</section>




I already have the tab functing as you suggest i.e clicking a heading shows the corresponding content. what`s lacking is dispyaing a separate div just beneath the tab section based on which tab is active.
